# Does GCP support automatic partition creation in cloud sql

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, database-partitioning

We have manual queries that we can run in our databases to create partition in a table.
For ex - Alter table  add partition()

But can we automate the process by some GCP feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. You could automate the manual queries (Cloud Scheduler + Cloud Functions that query your Cloud SQL instance) but there is no built-in feature to manage partitions on Cloud SQL

Comment: This partition needs to be created for multiple tables, and not only one.